# Fastest method for drawing a picture on the screen

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directdraw

I need to draw a stream of pictures (live video) on the screen in a Windows machine, and speed of drawing must be as fast as possible (i.e. lowest latency).
I tried DirectDraw with blitting from offscreen surface to primary and it introduces approximately 60 ms latency, which is too high. My monitor refresh rate is 60Hz.

Is there faster methods to accomplish this task? Thanks

Comment: DirectDraw is deprecated, you should use DXGI and Direct Composition.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it's deprecated, but before investing time into other methods - are you sure those are faster?